# Localhost de XAMPP no funciona correctamente

Tags: apache, xampp

Buenas tardes. Llevo bastantes horas liado con un problema que me ha surgido con XAMPP y me está dando dolores de cabeza.

Hace unos días, apache me funcionaba perfectamente ya que trabajo todos los días con el pero durante el fin de semana pasado, dejó de funcionar y no sé por qué razón. Xampp inicia con normalidad pero parece que "localhost" ahora no lo reconoce.

[image: XAMPP]

[image: LOCALHOST]

He probado ya a reinstalar XAMPP desde cero, a cambiarle los puertos por si fuese incompatibilidad con otros programas que usen el puerto 80 y varias cosas más pero sigue sin funcionarme.

¿Sabe alguien cual podría ser el fallo? Gracias

---

He mirado el archivo error.log de Apache y contiene lo siguiente:

```
[Fri May 06 09:16:45.989120 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1280:tid 604] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 06 09:16:46.097431 2016] [core:warn] [pid 1280:tid 604] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri May 06 09:16:46.168301 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1280:tid 604] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 06 09:16:46.827006 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1280:tid 604] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.20 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 06 09:16:46.827006 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1280:tid 604] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
[Fri May 06 09:16:46.827006 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1280:tid 604] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Fri May 06 09:16:46.840723 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1280:tid 604] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2592
[Fri May 06 09:16:47.305611 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2592:tid 704] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 06 09:16:47.426765 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2592:tid 704] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 06 09:16:47.461038 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2592:tid 704] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Has comprobado en el httpd.conf de apache que este escichando para la 127.0.0.1 y el puerto 80? Tambien deberia mirar el /path_apache/logs/error_log y por supuesto... no tendras un proxy habilitado en el navegador?

Comment: Ejecuta Xamp con permisos de administrador xamp-control.exe con el botón derecho y selecionar "ejecutar con permisos de administrador"

Comment: No tengo proxy habilitado y ya ejecutaba XAMPP con permisos de administrador. También miré el archivo log, aunque no se que significa cada error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He podido resolver finalmente el problema. Por alguna razón que aún desconozco, el archivo "hosts" había sido modificado y no tenía escrito 127.0.0.1 localhost. Así que añadí esa línea de nuevo y listo, todo funcionando.

Gracias de todas formas

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado, no olvides, en marcarte la respuesta cómo correcta

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver este problema yo hice lo siguiente:

1. Abrí el CMD con permisos de adminostrador.
2. Entre con la siguiente dirección: windows/system32/drivers/etc
   (La dirección que publicaron arriba esta mal, esta es la buena)
3. Ya una vez estando en la carpeta etc ponen "notepad hotst" y se les abrira un archivo de texto.
4. Debe estar así:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost 
   ::1 localhost
   ```
5. Si tiene un signo de gato al inicio y espacios, quitaselos
6. Si la dirección de 127.0.0.1 localhost esta repetido, borra la que este abajo del ::1 localhost, a mi me apareció dos veces y borre una.

Comment: Como comentario, chequen con ctrl+f5 actualizar su navegador, por que luego falla la cache y no se actualiza bien haciendo parecer que el xampp esta mal.

Answer (score 1):

Hay que mirar los puertos dentro de la configuración de *XAMPP*, en la esquina superior derecha donde dice **config**. Ingresa y abajo en los puestos, luego ingresa a **service and port setting** e ingresa los puertos correspondientes a los de los block de notas.

Comment: que tal si agregas una imagen a tu respuesta para ver donde se encuentra